# Why is my AC Wi-Fi speed about 150 Mbps but Windows claims it is 325 Mbps?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Lenovo Ideapad l340 with a built in Realtek 8821CE Wireless 802.11 AC network adapter. The OS is Windows 10 with latest updates. The fastest download speed I can reach is around 150 Mbps :

[image]

The cable modem is a CBN CH7465VF with a built in Wi-Fi router by the internet provider (Vodafone). My iPhone SE and other devices reach normal download speed and also the laptop is quick when I connect with an UTP cable. It is only the laptop and only through wifi where it is slow, so I suspect that something is wrong or misconfigured with the laptop wifi.

According to the product sheet of the wifi module

https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8821ce

it is supports AC and Mimo so it should be quick.

What can be the problem?

Here are the results of two independent measurements :

https://www.fast.com

[image]

https://www.speedtest.net/result/12013878102

[image]

I get the same result even if I disable the firewall and virus scanner

Comment: Please edit your question: What exact model of router do you have? Are the other devices connecting at AC as well? This could simply be a (frustrating) issue where the AC Wi-Fi adapter in the router isn’t playing nice with the AC Wi-Fi on the laptop.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I updated the post with the model number

Comment: The link speed isn't the user data bandwidth. Remember that Wi-Fi is not duplex.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparisons are a bit off. And I think Windows might be showing something close to reality.

TL/DR; how to analyze and compare the WiFi performance between the laptop and the phone:

1. Ensure your laptop has latest WiFi driver
2. Download a WiFi analysis tool (for example [inSSIDer](https://www.metageek.com/products/inssider/)) to see how crowded the WiFi environment is, and set your modem to broadcast on a channel with least amount of other devices
3. Ensure your laptop is the only device connected to the modem (obviously you can't do any kind of WiFi speed testing while streaming a movie or music on the wire...)
4. Go to https://speedtest.net and run the test
5. Put your phone on the table where the laptop was, and do the same test

That is a proper comparison. I'd also run speedtest on a wired connection just to see what the ISP actually gives.

Please ensure your phone is also connecting on the ac. If it's not ac-capable, you need to do the testing on whatever it's capable of. Comparison testing is only really valid when the parameters of the testing don't change. If using the same standard isn't possible, don't fret - the test will give you an indication anyway :-)

---

Here be dragons - i.e. tech stuff.

---

Firstly UTP vs WiFi. This comparison is invalid from the get-go. The wired connection between your laptop and the modem is 1Gb/s, full duplex, i.e. it can simultaneously transmit and receive at theoretical max of 1Gb/s each direction. Your internet connection speed is limited by your ISP contract (very few ppl run a GB connection home).

Secondly, what Windows shows as your WiFi link speed to be says nothing about the internet connectivity speed. It only shows the maximum transfer rate between your laptop's WiFi antenna and the antenna of the modem in the current situation. It doesn't even take into account the throughput between the modem's antenna and the WAN connection.

Lenovo sells this laptop with either 1x1 or 2x2 WiFi antenna configuration. Meaning 1 antenna / 1 stream, or 2 antennas / 2 streams (MiMo - Multi In, Multi Out). Theoretical max transfer rates are 433Mb/s and 867Mb/s, respectively. To actually achieve 2x2 performance both devices must support 2x2 MiMo.

Thirdly, as @Daniel B points out, WiFi is a shared, half-duplex connection. Unlike wired connection you can either send or receive, but not simultaneously. That's how radio works - a full-duplex WiFi would require one radio dedicated for send, one for receiving; again on both ends of the link.

"Shared" means that the available bandwidth is shared between connected clients. Assume an AP that provides 100Mb/s transfer rate. One client gets it all. When second client connects, they both get 50Mb/s. When third client connects, each gets 33.3Mb/s, and so on.

Please note, above I'm talking specifically about *theoretical* max performance. This is because any advertised transfer speeds are *always* referring to lab testing. In real life you can expect at best something like 2/3 - 3/4 of the advertised speed.

Explanation: all lab tests are done in absolute ideal conditions - devices are close to each other, enclosed in a Faraday cage. In real world you will always have interference from both WiFi and non-WiFi sources. WiFi sources are simply nearby WiFi devices using the same channel. Non-WiFi interference sources include things like alarm systems, microwave ovens, certain lighting fixtures... Non-WiFi interference can't be detected with standard WiFi analysis tools, only with a proper spectrum analyzer.

As it happens, Windows' reported 325Mb/s is 3/4 of 433Mb/s, so I suspect that either the laptop or the modem - or both - is only 1x1 capabile.

Transmit rates also depend on the distance between the device and the AP - the signal strength follows the inverse square law. In real life your device is further away from the AP than in lab testing, or might be moving around in which case the transmit/receive rates fluctuate constantly.

And that there is why HC gamers tend to use a wired connection :-)

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 for the long answer. I did all the things you wrote in point 1-5 before asking this question and still I can't go above 150 Mbps. My wifi router is able to serve higher speed because all other devices are quicker. According to the product sheet of the wifi module

https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8821ce

it is supports AC and Mimo so it should be quick, but it isn't

Comment: From your linked page: "802.11ac *1x1*, Wave-2 compatible with MU-MIMO"... and what was it I said about this again? You need to keep in mind that there are always two parts in the equation when talking about this kind of thing - the AP/Router and the wireless device. Which means there are more things to consider; just as an example the driver, OS and application versions... What exactly were the speedtest results with the phone and the laptop?

Comment: It’s is a win10 laptop with the latest updates and drivers. The IPhone SE has 300 Mbps the laptop 150-200 Mbps. Both devices next to the modem. I disconnected all other devices from the router so my laptop is connected exclusively and still…

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, add details to your question. For example I already edited it by changing "mobile phone" to "iPhone SE" and adding Win OS, tho' the changes aren't visible until reviewed and accepted by senior members of the community. OS and its version matters. IOS has no in-built firewall or virusscanner, Win does; and both affect your perceived performance - disable them  b4 testing. Remember SU isn't a tech support line where you get a single person helping you out; it's a community. You can't expect every community member to dig out details from extended commentaries.

Comment: Also; speedtest.net doesn't give you a range of speeds, it gives you two measured, exact speeds, one down, one up. You could upload screenshots of inSSDIder and speedtest results to imgur or similar and add links to your question. The devil's in the details - the more you give and the more precise they are, the better answers you can expect.

Comment: Hi @Peregrino69 I added the screenshots to the question. The same laptop has 300 Mbps downloadspeed through UTP cable (that is the max speed of my internet subscription) so I don't think it is a firewall or viruscanner issue, but do double check I turned them off and it had no effect